# PHP, Ajax, and the lifespan of the request

Tags: php, jquery, http, multithreading

I was wondering about the lifespan of a PHP script when called via Ajax.  Assume that there is a long-running (i.e. 30 seconds) PHP script on a server and that page is loaded via Ajax.  Before the script completes, the user closes the browser.  Does the script continue running to completion, is it terminated, or is this a function of the server itself (I'm running Apache fwiw).  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script will continue running. Closing the browser on the client does not notify the server to stop processing the request.

Comment: Thanks.  That was the answer I was hoping for.  I probably should have been more specific in my question about my request.  Thanks!

Comment: -1, because, well, false. A script usually keeps running because it hasn't got a non-connection message/quit, by virtue that the leniency for a 'broken' connection in HTTP is quite long, and as a stateless protocol it can only be detected by trying to send data. Most web-based scripts are done long before the timeout occurs. Heed the other `ignore_user_abort` mention if it is important to keep the script running, but even then the webserver itself might decide to kill it.

Comment: Thanks Wrikken, note I said "will continue running" not "will continue running to completion". It is as you say "script usually keeps running". Cheers

Comment: The question was literally "Does the script continue running to completion", you reply "will continue running", and when called on it defend the answer by claiming you did not say "will continue running to completion"? At the least the answer is not the answer to the question, but as someone who doesn't know how it works and actually trusts your answer it becomes misleading. No offense intended, keep up the good work and all, but clearly a 'there's a chance it will complete' was not the answer the OP was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

This may be of interest: [`ignore_user_abort()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php)

> ignore_user_abort — Set whether a client disconnect should abort script execution

However note

> PHP will not detect that the user has aborted the connection until an attempt is made to send information to the client.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a large time consuming script, then I would suggest splitting it up into chunks. Much better that way